# Wordpress, pagespeed, разное расположение скриптов на мобилках и десктопе

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed-insights

Сайт на wordpress, для улучшения показателей google pagespeed переместил все стили и скрипты в футер с помощью этого кода:

```
function footer_enqueue_scripts(){
    remove_action('wp_head','wp_print_scripts');
    remove_action('wp_head','wp_print_head_scripts',9);
    remove_action('wp_head','wp_enqueue_scripts',1);
    add_action('wp_footer','wp_print_scripts',5);
    add_action('wp_footer','wp_enqueue_scripts',5);
    add_action('wp_footer','wp_print_head_scripts',5);
}
add_action('after_setup_theme','footer_enqueue_scripts');
```

который добавил в `functions.php`.
В инспекторе кода все стили и скрипты в футере.
В результате на мобилках это сработало, т.е. pagespeed не выдаёт предложений по оптимизации "Удалите код JavaScript и CSS, блокирующий отображение верхней части страницы".
А вот на десктопной версии это предложение есть, т.е. получается на мобильной версии стили и скрипты переместились в футер, а на десктопной версии нет.
Хотя если посмотреть в инспекторе кода, все стили и скрипты в футере.
Как такое может быть? Почему когда все стили и скрипты в футере, для pagespeed они всё равно в head?
Для мобилок показатель 75, для десктопа 45

Comment: Я надеюсь вы хоть прелоадер сделали? PageSpeed может не сразу обновить информацию.

Comment: @DaemonHK, а при чём здесь прелоадер, страница загружается почти за секунду, прелоадер и не нужен. Он вообще тут роли не играет, добавил критические стили в шапку, чтобы контент сразу прорисовывался, а все основые стили в футере

Comment: За секунду это где? На вашей локалке?

Comment: @DaemonHK, разве вопрос про скорость загрузки?
тем более я ведь выше сказал, что добавил критические стили для предзагрузки

Comment: Это ладно, полемика все) прошло 3 дня, гугл должен был обновить информацию уже сто раз, как успехи?

Comment: @DaemonHK та же ситуация

Comment: Значит у вас скрипты по разному подключаются, как вариант попробуйте другой анализатор

Comment: @DaemonHK, если бы по разному подключались, я бы об этом узнал первый. footer.php и header.php везде одинаковый